# Using Entity.json for sending JSONObject to server

Tags: rest, jersey, json

I am new to jersey Rest API and got stuck with use of Entity.json() method. I am using Entity.json(obj) to request post call, but I am not sure how should I get the obj at server side. here is my example code

Client side :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{"testing":"check"}");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost/test/postcall");
Response res = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(obj));
```

Server Side

```
@POST
@Path("/postcall")
public Response()
{
   return Response.status(200).entity("post called").build();
}
```

I am not sure what param I should used to get the JSONObject passed from client to my server side code.

Comment: What has this got to do with JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
Entity.entity(obj.toString(),"application/json"),
```

and at server side got as a String parameter ,

```
public Response(String input)
```